# Error while adding Left Join to Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to add a left join to my Linq query as below;

```
var leftJoin = (from person in ISession.Query<Person>()       
                    join cars in ISession.Query<Cars>()
                    on person.carGuid equals cars.Guid into gj
                    from subCar in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
                    select new carDto
                    {
                          carBrand= subCar.carBrand,
                          ownerName = person.Name
    
                    }).toList();
```

I am getting this error;
***NHibernate.HibernateException: 'Query Source could not be identified: ItemName = gj, ItemType = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1***

Is there a way to fix this? I need to add left outer join to my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but we usually get this error when the dbSet/repository is not set, in your instance the `ISession.Query<Person>()`, can you check you are not getting a null reference there?

Other than that, this is the correct way to do the left join in Linq.